# How to define an empty object in typescript

Tags: typescript

**Background**

Stuck with typescript. I understand this declarations:

```
let varName:number; //null,string,..declare simple variables.  
let arrName:string[] // or arrName:number[]. etc
```

Apparently this is used for objects:

```
//knowing type of the property
let obj: {property:string, also:number[]} = {property:'hello', also:[1,2,3]}

//now knowing the type of the property
let obj: {property:any, also:any[]} = {property: a && b || c, also:[1,'string', 'etc']}
```

But what happens when we don't know the names of the properties in advance?

Particularly, I am trying to translate this JS bit:

```
let myObj = {}
myObj[prop] = value
```

but we don't know the names of the properties in advance.

Comment: `Record<string, unknown>` or if you prefer to throw type safety out `Record<string, any>`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have a few options:

1. You can use an [index signature type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#index-signatures) that allows any string or any number, for instance:

   ```
   let myObj: {[key: string]: number} = {};
   myObj[prop] = value;
   ```

   ...allows any string property name, with the values expected to be numbers. (Or you can use `{[key: number]: number}` to make the keys numbers. `string` and `number` are your only two index signature options.)
2. You can use the [`Record` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#recordkeys-type), for example `Record<string, number>` which does much the same thing as the above:

   ```
   let myObj: Record<string, number> = {};
   myObj[prop] = value;
   ```
3. You can use a `Map` instead of an object:

   ```
   let myObj: Map<string, number> = new Map();
   myObj.set(prop, value);
   ```

In all three of those, `number` as the value type is just an example, it can be any type you want (including a [union type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types)), or [`unknown`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#unknown) if you won't know the type, or [`any`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#any) if you want to allow any type.

It may be obvious, but I'll say it anyway: This does mean TypeScript can't help you with using the wrong property name on the object. :-) But that's inevitable if the property name is a runtime thing.

Comment: I've come back to this answer a few times; works great!